# Is there any use of dictionaries which reference itself in its value?

Tags: python

Example:

```
>>> x = {'a' : 3, 'b' : 5, 'c' : 6}
>>> x['d'] = x

>>> x
{'a': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': {...}}
​
>>> x['d']
{'a': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': {...}}

​>>> x['d']['d']
{'a': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': {...}}

​>>> x['d']['d']['d']
{'a': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': {...}}
```

I guess it is infinitely looped since it is referencing itself. I just wanted to know if there is any use case for such dictionaries in real world? If yes, any examples?

Comment: I don't know that you'd ever want to handle this with a dictionary, but filesystems are often self-referential in this way. The `.` and `..` files in  each directory refer to the directory itself, and to its parent, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

No actually I don't think that's a very useful thing. The author's opinion even leans the other way that it's hard enough to have objects copied in all the right spots in python.

One obvious possibility would be to subclass `dict` and create (or interface) an RPG like Nethack inside the python CLI that way. You could even add some sort of UI to it. Basically, dictionaries and other mapping types are "useful enough" in python without recursion, though.